# Webpack 2 Hot-reload Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, react-hot-loader

I have just upgraded from Webpack 1.x to Webpack 2.x for my React project, and everything is running nicely, except hot-reloading. The issue that I have is that every time I update a file in the project, the HotModuleReplacementPlugin falls over with the error `Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`.

I have managed to locate the issue, which seems to me like a bug within HotModuleReplacementPlugin.js, but want to be sure that I haven't done something odd in my configuration (i.e. I'm not Chunking the build, which may cause this?) before raising as an issue/PR within the Webpack repo.

The code in HotModuleReplacementPlugin.js on line 113 `var currentChunk = this.chunks.find(chunk => chunk.id === chunkId);` returns `-1` in my build, rather than a Chunk object, which is what logic following this line is relying on.

I've been able to "fix" my local version by changing the if statement on line 114 from `if(currentChunk) {` to `if(currentChunk && currentChunk.modules) {` but is there something I've missed here?

Answer (score 0):

I've got to the bottom of this issue now. This was being caused by the dependency [q-io](https://github.com/kriskowal/q-io/issues/160), which in turn had a dep of [collections](https://github.com/montagejs/collections). Collections overrides the in-built `find` function on an array and implements it incorrectly, so that -1 is returned instead of undefined.